# Trigger wont work for my Borderbrush

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, triggers

**      First i had a problem of changing background when IsMouseOver, but i
      fixed it lated and now my trigger for borderbrush wont work when
      IsAnabled="False" but Background and foreground works. Heres the code:**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="btnBase">
    <Setter Property="Foreground"           Value="{DynamicResource btnBaseForegroundColor}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"          Value="{DynamicResource btnBaseBorderBrushColor}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background"           Value="{DynamicResource btnBaseBackgroundColor}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily"           Value="/Resources/Fonts/Source Sans Pro/#Source Sans Pro"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight"           Value="Bold"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize"             Value="15"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"      Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding"              Value="14,3,14,3"/>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"   BorderThickness="1" Padding="14,3,14,3"  >

                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#65A83B"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Yellow"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Are you missing `BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"` on the <Border> control?

Comment: Try giving your `<Border>` an `x:Name="MyButtonName"` and in your trigger setter use `TargetName="MyButtonName"`. It looks like it is targeting the property `<ControlTemplate.BorderBrush>`, and not `<Border.Brush>` property of your `<Border>` inside your Template

Comment: Thanks alot guys, works fine now!